# Styles have disappeared despite being referenced correctly

Tags: php, html, css

Help!!! My worst nightmare has come true. [My site](http://www.lifestylerevolutionstx.com/index.php/) is broken. It happened after attempting to install some PHP scripts to automatically minify and concatenate CSS and JS files. These were MISER and Minify. Each one created problems, so I took them out. Now none of the styles are showing, despite the fact that the CSS files are referenced properly. I had backed up the site prior to making these changes, but restoring the backup does nothing to fix the problem. Does anyone have any ideas? I am in crisis mode and nothing I do seems to fix the problem!

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: _"restoring the backup does nothing to fix the problem"_ Well that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Didn't make sense to me either, but it was an Apache command that was rewriting the CSS references to reference cached files that had been deleted. Restoring backups from within the CMS did nothing because the server was still rewriting the document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code is invalid:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/themes/C5-LR/css/foundation.css'); ?>" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/themes/C5-LR/typography.css'); ?>" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/themes/C5-LR/css/main.css'); ?>" />
```

`'); ?>` should be removed in each link.

Answer (score 1):

```
<link href="/themes/C5-LR/css/foundation.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/themes/C5-LR/typography.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/themes/C5-LR/css/main.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet">
```

All these links are broken, remove ); and you should be good just like the above answer. You only need to reference those if you are using an

`@import url('some-css-file.css');`

instead of